# Technicality in proof of $\binom{m+n}{l} = \sum_{k=0}^l \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{l-k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, binomial-coefficients

This is from *Analysis I* by Herbert Amann, Joachim Escher. I want to make sure I understand everything correctly, so I'm sorry if this seems nitpicky.

After introducing formal power series $R[X]$ (functions in $R^{\mathbb{N}}$) of a ring $R$ with unity and polynomials as a subring of $R[X]$, there is a proof of the identity
$$\binom{m+n}{l} = \sum_{k=0}^l \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{l-k},\quad l,m,n\in\mathbb N$$
as an application of $R[X]$ being a ring.
Let $X$ denote the polynomial with $x_1=1$ and $x_i=0$ for $i\neq 1$.
Their proof is as follows:

Since $X$ and $1\in R[X]$ commute, we can use the binomial theorem for rings to compute
$$(1+X)^j=\sum_{i=0}^j\binom{j}{i}X^i,\quad j\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Now we compute the two sides of $(1+X)^m(1+X)^n=(1+X)^{m+n}$.
We have
$$\begin{align}(1+X)^m(1+X)^n &= \left(\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}X^k\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}X^j\right)\\
&=\sum_l\left( \sum_{k=0}^l\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{l-k} \right)X^l\end{align}\tag{A}$$
where the second equality is the definition of multiplication of polynomials. Also
$$(1+X)^{m+n}=\sum_{l=0}^{m+n}\binom{m+n}{l}X^l.\tag{B}$$
Comparing coefficients in (A) and (B) gives the identity.

**My issue is that the binomial coefficients which lie in $\mathbb N$ are not technically the coefficients of the polynomial, which lie in $R$.** Given $r\in R$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, $n\cdot r$ is the $n$-fold sum of $r$. So, for example, isn't the $l$th coefficient of the polynomial in (B) really $\binom{m+n}{l}\cdot 1_R$?
Then the proof is really asserting that
$$\binom{m+n}{l}\cdot 1_R = \sum_{k=0}^l \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{l-k}\cdot 1_R$$
for any ring $R$.

If my understanding is correct so far, I think letting $R=\mathbb Z$ recovers the original identity since $n\cdot 1_{\mathbb Z}=n$. It's just that the integers haven't been introduced yet.

Comment: I don't understand your uncertainty. This equation is true regardless of the ring you consider the binomial coefficients to reside in. The binomial coefficients may not have the value you'd expect in the given ring but the identity still holds. For example, in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, every binomial coefficient either equals $0$ or $1$.

Comment: I thought the binomial coefficients lie in $\mathbb{N}$? At least for my definition of binomial coefficients, this is the case.

Comment: They are typically defined as the coefficients that appear in the expansion of $(1+X)^n$. If you take polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ then of course for example$$(1+X)^2=1+2X+X^2=1+X^2$$i.e. $\binom21=2=0$.

Comment: @PeterForeman: That amounts to saying that the proof really is asserting the last displayed formula. This is fine if that is what the authors say that they’re proving, and that depends on how we are to understand the binomial coefficients in the first displayed formula. The OP took them to be the usual ones; if that’s the case, and the ring of integers hasn’t yet been formally introduced, then the OP is correct in thinking that there is a technical problem, unless the authors are simply taking $\Bbb Z$ for granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are technically correct. Every ring $R$ has a canonical unit map $\mathbb{Z} \to R$ given by taking multiples of the unit, and it's an extremely common abuse of notation to write $n \in R$ when we mean $n \cdot 1_R \in R$. If $R$ has positive characteristic (meaning that this map has nontrivial kernel) then $n \cdot 1_R = m \cdot 1_R$ need not imply $n = m$.

Of course everything is fine if we set $R = \mathbb{Z}$, as you say. I have no idea why the authors would want to work in the generality of $R$ an arbitrary ring just to prove [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity). There are fun things you can do with binomial coefficients $\bmod p$ that involve taking $R = \mathbb{F}_p$, though.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicions. I think the authors just wanted to demonstrate some kind of application to bring the exposition more down to earth. From the book: "As a simple application of the fact that $R[X]$ is a ring, we prove the following addition theorem for binomial coefficients..."

Comment: @Lilypad: if you want a real application take $R = \mathbb{F}_p$ and use the fact that $(x + y)^p = x^p + y^p$ in characteristic $p$ to prove Lucas' theorem, this is lots of fun: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem